# Programmatically add context menu on Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have looked at several similar questions but I can't get this to work, I want to add subitems to a context menu when I right click a project or folder in the `Project Explorer` view.

I added the root element in the `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
     allPopups="true"
     class="com.my.menu.MyMenu"
     locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
  </menuContribution>
```

The `MyMenu` class extends `ExtensionContributionFactory` and I'm overriding the `createContributionItems()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void createContributionItems(final IServiceLocator serviceLocator, final IContributionRoot additions) {
    // build a command-based contribution parameters
    CommandContributionItemParameter pAA = new CommandContributionItemParameter(
            serviceLocator,
            "Submenu_CommandAA",
            "my.menu.root",
            SWT.PUSH);
    pAA.label = "Command AA";

    // create actual contribution items and add them to the given additions reference
    CommandContributionItem itemAA = new CommandContributionItem(pAA);
    itemAA.setVisible(true);
    additions.addContributionItem(itemAA, null);
}
```

Then when I right click a project I get this error:

```
!MESSAGE Unable to create menu item "Submenu_CommandAA", command "my.menu.root" not defined
```

Comment: Have you defined the command using the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point?

Comment: I don't have a command defined in the plugin.xml, I thought I needed to create the command programmatically using `CommandContributionItem` instead of defining it in the plugin.xml

Comment: Is your contribution going into Eclipse or your own RCP Application? I ask because if its an RCP application there are hooks in code where you can do this.

Comment: `CommandContributionItem` does not define a command, it just references an existing one.

Comment: @DuncanKrebs Yes, it is an RCP application

Comment: @greg-449 but if it just references an existing command, how can I dynamically create new commands?. I was looking at the `MenuManager` API, seems to be way more easy to use but I'm not sure if it can contribute to the context menu of the Project Explorer view

Comment: It is very unusual to define commands dynamically, they are normally declared in a plugin.xml using the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point.